# How to create bitmap index for this query

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, indexing

I'm trying to create a bitmap index for this query:

```
SELECT "TAB2"."TAB2ID","TAB1"."TAB1ID"
FROM "TAB1","TAB2"
WHERE ((("TAB1"."YESNO" = 'Y' ) 
AND ("TAB2"."LOCID" = "TAB1"."LOCID" ) ) 
AND ("TAB2"."YESNO" = 'Y' ) ) 
ORDER BY "TAB1"."LOCNO";
```

I've tried multiple bitmap indexes, but none of them seem to get used, even if I try to give the query a hint to use the bitmap index. Even a index on just tab2 doesn't seem to do anything.

This is one that I tried but that did nothing, even after gathering index and table stats:

```
CREATE BITMAP INDEX TAB2_TAB1_BIT_IDX 
ON TAB2(TAB2.YESNO,TAB1.YESNO)
FROM    TAB1        ,       TAB2 
WHERE   TAB2.LOCID = TAB1.LOCID
```

Tab1 contains 2 N and 29 Y, Tab2 contains 30000 'N' and 240000 'Y'.
What should be the code for the bitmap index, and are there other ways to optimize this query?

Answer (score 1):

It must be this one:

```
CREATE BITMAP INDEX TAB1_BIT_IDX  ON TAB1 (YESNO);
CREATE BITMAP INDEX TAB2_BIT_IDX  ON TAB2 (YESNO);
```

General note: usually a single Bitmap Index on a table does not help so much. The big gain of Bitmap Indexes you get when you define several Bitmap Indexes. 
A single Bitmap Index has low selectivity but the combination of several Indexes should be selective. In this case you use Bitmap Indexes properly!

Comment: According to http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_builder_bitmap_join_idx.htm and other sources it should be possible on joins. It it more effective o=to just put multiple bit indexes in place than to make on with the specific join of the query?

Comment: Yes, I see. I never used Bitmap Join Index - I even didn't know they exist.